# How to access the content of Eclipse stacktrace console programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I was wondering how to access the stack trace console of Eclipse IDE? I was trying to convert the IConsole object into MessageConsole to get the content, but it is showing cast exception. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```java
ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();
IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();

for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++) {
    try {
        MessageConsole myconsole=(MessageConsole)existing[i];
        System.out.println(myconsole.getDocument().get());
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessageConsole is only one of many possible implementations of the IConsole interface. Try to cast to TextConsole (org.eclipse.ui.console.TextConsole). TextConsole is the superclass of many common console classes (but there may be some console implementations left, which have another base class):

```
TextConsole myconsole = (TextConsole) existing[i];
```